# What is the best way to simplify the following code?

Tags: python, spring

```
if report == True:  
    print ("\tActive parts:\t%s")%(len(pact)) # TOTAL P Part and Active
    print ("\tDiscontinued parts:\t%s")%(len(pdisc)) # TOTAL P Part and Discontinued
    print ("\tSlow-moving parts:\t%s")%(len(pslow)) # TOTAL P Part and Slow-moving
    print ("\tObsolete parts:\t%s")%(len(pobs)) # P TOTAL Part and Obsolete
```

How could I best simplify the above? I have roughly 80 other print statements such as that which are steadily make the code very difficult to work with?

Comment: Are they all local namespace variables?

Comment: Yes, contained within one function.

Comment: Strip the `== True`. It won't make those 80 lines any less painful, but it's easy to fix and can make devs so angry ;) (Okay, serious: What are you doing?!? 80 variables in a function? I think this code may habe more serious problems than the number of print statements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-factor your code so that your individual variables are stored in a dictionary, e.g.,

```
data['pact']  = ...
data['pdisc'] = ...
```

Or even as attributes of a class,

```
class Data:
    pact = ...
    pdisc = ...
```

Then you'd create a separate list of strings to describe each attribute, such as:

```
longnames = {"pact": "Active parts", "pdisc": "Discontinued parts", ... }
```

Then you can print them like this:

```
if report:
    for key, name in values:
        print "\t%s\t%d" % (name, len(data[key])) # if using a dict
        print "\t%s\t%d" % (name, len(getattr(data, key))) # if using a class
```

Answer (score 2):

Write a template as a "constant" and then `print( template % dictionary_of_values)`

**To clarify:**

```
template = """\tActive parts:\t%(pactlen)d
\tDiscontinued parts:\t%(pdisclen)d
..."""
...
values = {'pactlen':len(pact), 'pdisclen':len(pdics) }
print(template % values)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a list of tuples containing all the labels and values, and do a loop like so:

```
if report:
    values = [
        ("Active parts:", pact),
        ("Discontinued parts:", pdisc),
        # etc...
    ]
    for label, value in values:
        print ("\t{}\t{}".format(label, len(value)))
```

Comment: I'd actually drop the len() call from values, and put it into the loop. Otherwise, this is what I would have proposed myself as well.

Comment: you should use "if report:" rather than "if report == True:"

Comment: Indeed. Didn't notice it as I was focusing on the "main part".

Answer (score 0):

Define a method so you can send a list and join the list with '\n'